# sql query with alias name

Tags: c#, sql, alias

i have a table with this columns--- Or

```
orgid ispaid validity      noofthingstoTake

1      yes    2010-06-05      20
2      yes    2010-06-09       7
```

i have used this query(to join two more tableS):

```
select distinct B.RequirementID,A.OrganizationID 
from 
Organization A,RequirementsDetailsforOrganization B,validityorgdet F
where A.OrganizationID=B.OrganizationID and F.orgid=A.OrganizationID and
 F.ispaid=1 and F.validity>=GETDATE() and 

  F.noofthingstoTake> ??
```

but i dont know how to check the (noofthingstaken) over here. it should not exceed 20. im passing this query from my code behind page to the Sql. how to get the query excute to check it should not exceed the noofthingstaken

pls help me out....????

Comment: I don't really understand your question. I presume `F.noofthingstoTake <= 20` is not what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct B.RequirementID,A.OrganizationID from 
Organization A,RequirementsDetailsforOrganization B,validityorgdet F
where A.OrganizationID=B.OrganizationID and F.orgid=A.OrganizationID and
 F.ispaid=1 and F.validity>=GETDATE() and   F.noofthingstoTake <= 20
```

Comment: no this 20 will differ depending on the data inside the table

Comment: sorry will u please explain little bit more i didn't get you what u mean?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `noofthingstoTake` is actually an alias and not a column name in your table.  You can't use column aliases outside of the `select` clause because they don't actually exist until the query is done running.  So, you can't compare directly to `noofthingstoTake`, but must instead refer to the actual field name that that column came from.  If it's an expression, just use the entire expression.  Note that if it's an aggregate, you'll need to put it in a `having` clause, not a `where` clause.

(Note: You really should have posted your entire query)

Comment: ithink she already mention "noofthingstoTake" is her column name (i have a table with this columns)

Comment: I was just basing it off of the title of the question.